# Reusable Delete PHP Statement?

Tags: php

I was wondering how to make my code less cluttered and more re-usable. I have seperate delete.php files for deleting specific data from pages. For example I have Genre,Platform and Customers.

**Genre Delete**

```
//get value of ?id= from the url
$DeleteID = $_GET['id'];

echo $DeleteID;

require("connect.php");

//Linking
$link = connectToDB();

//SQL Query
$sql =    "DELETE
                FROM Genre
                WHERE GenreID = ".$DeleteID;

//Execute
$result = $link->query($sql);

//Check
if ($link->affected_rows == 1) {
        header( "Location: genre.php" );
}
else {
    echo "Didn't Work";
}
```

**Platform Delete**

```
<?php
session_start();

//get value of ?id= from the url
$DeleteID = $_GET['id'];

echo $DeleteID;

require("connect.php");

//Linking
$link = connectToDB();

//SQL Query
$sql =    "DELETE
                FROM Platform
                WHERE PlatformID = ".$DeleteID;

//Execute
$result = $link->query($sql);

//Check
if ($link->affected_rows == 1) {
        header( "Location: platform.php" );
}
else {
    echo "Didn't Work";
}
```

I wanted to know if it was possible for these to be made into 1 delete file that I can alter, or statement. The user is redirected to these pages through a button in a table, and it redirects to the delete page with the PK ID of the record.

Comment: Pass a second GET parameter that tells the script where to delete from - and then use that in a switch statement. And go read up on SQl injection, before you proceed.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, while this is a programming question it is somewhat outside of the scope of the questions we usually help with. Questions about code syntax and best practices are better asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You could pass another variable into the URL to indicate what you want to be deleted (Genre, Platform, Customers, etc.).

Granted, it becomes very easy to create a mess of if/else statements, but it would keep all the functionality limited to one file.

Answer (score 0):

you could write a small helper function:

```
function deleteMe($link, $table, $id){
  //SQL Query

  $id = intval($id);
  $sql =    "DELETE
                FROM `$table`
                WHERE `{$table}ID` = ".$id;

  //Execute
  $result = $link->query($sql);

  return $link->affected_rows;
}
```

You could then include this on a single delete page and use it as needed, passing your table and id in with GET params.